# Is it possible to have access to the library files in android?

Tags: java, android

I've done some research on whether accessing the library files themselves is possible from the app, and I haven't found anything yet, is it possible?. With "Library files" I mean the"android.jar", "android-support-v4.jar". Those files are under the "Referenced Libraries" and "Android Private Libraries" from the package explorer in Eclipse, but I'm wondering if I can have access them from the application itself. I've been looking at the Android built in classes, and I can't seem to find anything that would let me access them. First I looked in the PackageManager class, there is a property named "ApplicationInfo".

`ApplicationInfo info = myContext.getPackageManager()
                        .getPackageInfo(myContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES).applicationInfo;`

Then I did...

`String[] libs = info.sharedLibraryFiles`

Nothing comes back.....
I also tried

`File libDir = new File(info.nativeLibraryDir);`

and "libDir" is empty.

Is it possible to retrieve the .jar files the application uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If your **application itself** reads the pseudo text file `/proc/self/maps` you will find a list of the libraries (both .jar and .odex as well as native .so) which are either in use by your application process, or preemptively loaded into shared pages for all apps by zygote.

Note however that those used at *runtime* are not the same as those used at *build time*.  You will find that what you link against as "android.jar" is actually implemented on the device in other files.  And jar's which are attached to your project source will get collapsed into your code itself, as if they were part of it and not distinct .jar's.

Comment: I retrieved the contents of that file...I added this info in my question

Comment: As I already explained in my answer, the functionality represented at build time by the sdk's "android.jar" is implemented by **different files** at **runtime**.  Additionally, you've omitted the "interesting" parts of the maps file in your posting.

Comment: Sorry, I pulled up that file with an terminal emulator, not with the app, so that must have been the libraries of the emulator

Comment: There are some .jar files from the app's list.

Comment: By "linked" I meant that your apk does not include the functionality, but rather depends on the device's Android installation to provide it.  By "attached" I meant that you supply to the build process a jar actually containing the functionality, which becomes incorporated into your apk as it you had the actual source code in your project - in which case the fact that it came from a jar and not from source is nearly invisible at runtime.

Comment: I only have one question for you. What do you mean with a "linked" jar file and a "attached" jar file?